# Schema Mapping Single object schema with List of Object schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2013r2

I have an input schema which contains a single object in which it have a root node and a datanode and the elements. I have a WCF Method which accepts List of objects as input. I am trying to map these two schemas. But when i am sending the input file it only transforms the first set. [image]

Is there anything additional I have to do to map this?
**Input Schema**

```
<ns0:Emp xmlns:ns0="http://SampleAppWithExcelToXmlWCF.InputSchema">
 <Add>
  <EmailId>EmailId_0</EmailId> 
  <Phone>Phone_0</Phone> 
  <EmpName>EmpName_0</EmpName> 
  <EmpNo>EmpNo_0</EmpNo> 
  <ActiveInd>ActiveInd_0</ActiveInd> 
  </Add>
  <Add>
  <EmailId>EmailId_1</EmailId> 
  <Phone>Phone_1</Phone> 
  <EmpName>EmpName_1</EmpName> 
  <EmpNo>EmpNo_1</EmpNo> 
  <ActiveInd>ActiveInd_1</ActiveInd> 
  </Add>
  <Add>
  <EmailId>EmailId_2</EmailId> 
  <Phone>Phone_2</Phone> 
  <EmpName>EmpName_2</EmpName> 
  <EmpNo>EmpNo_2</EmpNo> 
  <ActiveInd>ActiveInd_2</ActiveInd> 
  </Add>
  </ns0:Emp>
```

Above is the input schema sample

As output I want it to be multiple EmployeeDO's as in the schema

The input schema is generated by using a custom ExcelToXML Convertor Pipeline.

Comment: Do you mean the source can loop on Add?

Comment: Can you add a sample message and expected output to your question?  And if they aren't large the two schemas?

Comment: @Johns-305 - Yes.. you are right...

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried a looping functoid connecting 'Add' and 'EmployeeDO'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Connect Add and EmployeeDO with a Looping Functiod.
2. You may have to adjust the min/max Occurs on both sides since that does have an effect, despite the Looping Functoid.  Basically, both should be max=unbounded.

Comment: @MidhunMathew just remember that it needs to be set to a positive integer greater than 1 - if `maxOccurs` is left blank, the default is 1 and the mapper won't allow it to loop.